# ASP.NET MVC Does the WCF service reference/proxy have to exist in the web app assembly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

We want our web applications separated from our WCF web services. We don't want the web app to know if it's hitting any WCF services. Therefore we don't want any WCF web service references defined in the web app assembly.

What I'm trying to do is create a separate WCF wrapper assembly that would contain the WCF service reference and the necessary configuration in the `app.config` file. Method in the WCF wrapper would be called from the Web app. When I create the WCF service reference and configuration in the Web App assembly it works fine. When I put the WCF web reference and config file in WCF wrapper assembly it complains about not finding the endpoint. It doesn't look like it's finding the `app.config` file in the wrapper assembly.

So in summary I want a structure as follows:

```
Web app --> WCF wrapper (with WCF service references and config) --> BAL layer --> etc
```

Config file (web.config if in web app assembly, app.config if in WCF wrapper assembly):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmailValidator" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEmailValidator" contract="EmailProxy.IEmailValidator"
       name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmailValidator" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Do I have to create the WCF service references in the web app assembly or can I do it in the WCF wrapper?

**Error Message:**

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'EmailProxy.IEmailValidator' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This goes back to the old truth that the .NET configuration system doesn't support config files for class libraries - it expects the config for a class library to be in the **host application** that uses the class library - e.g. in your web application.

It's really not a WCF problem - it's a general .NET design decision that the .NET team made. A class library might have an `app.config` file in the solution, and that might even be compiled into a `myclasslibrary.dll.config` - but that file is **not inspected and parsed** by the .NET configuration system.

Therefore, in your case, your web app cannot find the config and thus cannot configure any endpoints and that's why it fails.

You basically have three major options:

- live with this restriction and put your WCF config into the web app's `web.config`
- find an alternate way to configure your WCF service library, e.g. from some other source, like a database
- invest a lot of effort into making your WCF service library actually look into and pick up your class library's separate config file

Comment: Thanks.  This might be a stupid question, Does the WCF proxy service reference have to be created in the host application as well?

Comment: @Elim99: what do you mean by "host application"? WCF is always two parts - the **server** (which implements the service methods and is hosted in e.g. IIS or a Windows service), and one or multiple **clients** which are use a client-side proxy to talk to the server. As such, only clients need a client-side proxy, obviously...

Comment: What I mean is that I have a host application assembly that calls a WCF wrapper class in another assembly which then calls the service methods.  My question is:  Can the proxy just exist in the WCF wrapper assembly?  Currently I have to setup the proxy in both assemblies even though the "host application assembly" doesn't directly call the service method.

Comment: @Elm99: yes, in that case, your "host application" becomes the client for another WCF service - and a client always needs the appropriate client-side proxy!

Comment: I just find it annoying that I have to create the proxy class in 2 assemblies (Host application assembly and WS Wrapper assembly).

Answer (score 0):

You can load a custom config file via

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"c:\myapp\wcfsettings.config.anything";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```