# class implemeting service contracts base class for another class WCF

Tags: wcf, endpoint, servicecontract

I have a class implementing a service contract. Another class being derived from this class and in turn implements another service contract

```
Class A: a.IA
{

}

Class B: A, b.IB
{

}
```

How do I expose the endpoints for contract IB?

The endpoints I tried:

```
<service name="B">
   <endpoint address="ep1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="a.A1" />   
   <endpoint address="ep2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="b.B1" />
</service>
```

If I do this, it gives error

> Service 'B' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no
>   endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can
>   set up default endpoints, but only if the service implements only a
>   single ServiceContract. Either change the service to only implement a
>   single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service
>   explicitly in the configuration file.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

the config had a typo above.

```
    <service name="B">
       <endpoint address="ep1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="a.IA" />   
       <endpoint address="ep2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="b.IB" />
    </service>
```

The template I am using for this is WCF Rest template 4.0 (if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

The service class that implements the service is `B` - and you use that correctly, as far as I can tell.

The contract that this service class implements is `IB` - but that doesn't really show up in your config.

Try this:

```
<service name="B">
   <endpoint address="ep1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="a.IA" />   
   <endpoint address="ep2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="b.IB" />
</service>
```

The **contract** in the endpoint must denote a service **interface** (typically) that defines the services method - that interface must have the `[ServiceContract]` attribute applied to it.

OK - so that was a typo and your contracts are correct - but my question is then: are the `a.` and `b.` prefixes on the contracts the namespaces those contracts live in?

And if yes: why isn't the service tag using that namespace, too?? Does it make any difference if you change it to `name="b.B"` :

```
<service name="b.B">
   <endpoint address="ep1" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="a.IA" />   
   <endpoint address="ep2" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="b.IB" />
</service>
```

Comment: opps thats a typo, it should be a.IA and b.IB. Thats what I tried, and still got that error. Both the interfaces have servicecontract attribute

Comment: yes they are namespaces. tried with what you suggested, same error!

Comment: @Priya10: updated my response - aren't you missing a namespace prefix on the service's `name=` attribute, maybe??

Comment: @Priya10: ok, so **where** do you implement those services? Is this a separate class library and your config is only in the class library's `app.config` ?? That won't be picked up by the WCF runtime! (I [just answered that very same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367401/asp-net-mvc-does-the-wcf-service-reference-proxy-have-to-exist-in-the-web-app-ass/7367859#7367859), basically)

Comment: Excuse me if I dint get you right. I am trying to run it using browser, since these are restful services, I should be able to see them using browser. The endpoints are on the web.config of the service. This works when the class itself implements two service contract , so whats the difference when it implements a class which implements service contract and another service contract